# No errors, just "<program name> has stopped working"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is not an outright coding-question, but when I get any kind of error at run-time, all VS does is open a window saying " has stopped working", and the usual about trying to find a solution on the web.

Even if I make a simple "division by zero" or Convert.ToInt32 on an empty string.

It began after my PC by itself updated to Win10. Before that, I got fine feedback on errors.

I use VS2008, and as far as I can see, everything else works flawless on Win10.

I believe it must be some setting in VS, but why it has changed in the update-process I have no idea.

Can anybody help with this one?

Comment: How are you executing the programmes? Are you getting this when they are executed in debug mode from visual studio itself?

Comment: I'm running it from Visual Studio itself. In debug-mode. And this is where I get it. (Thank for the fast reply :-)

Comment: Repair the VS installation!

Comment: When upgrading your OS, VS might get broken, it did not happen to me but a friend of mine had the problem. A repair did the trick for him.

Comment: I usually just go into the bin folder and remove all the files.  The operating system does some funny things and locks the executable so the compiler can't rebuilt the application.  I get this problem a lot with Windows 7.

Comment: Removing all files from the Bin-folder did not work. And this problem occurs on completely new project too.

Comment: I have tried doing a re-install, but now it says that "A problem has been encountered while loading setup components."

Comment: (Allright, it sends the comment when I hit 'enter'. I'll try avoiding that.)  Now, Maybe VS 2008 is just too old to cooperate with Win10. It seem that if I get lucky uninstalling it, I'll maybe not be able to install it again...!

Comment: Okay, from this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469814/visual-studio-2008-stopped-displaying-errors) I got the suggestion compiling to 'x86' instead of 'anyCpu'.  It worked! Now I get errors again. (It does _not_ work if I use 'x64', don't ask why)  Hovever, this is a workaround, not a solution, since my other PC, which recently have upgraded to Win10 has the same VS2008, compiles to AnyCPU, and shows errors like it should. Something **is** wrong, but now I can at least move on with my work.

Comment: And of course: Thank you everyone for your time!