# How to handle C# AppDomain.UnhandledException

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have read these two pages from msdn: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So I constructed this simple Web Forms app:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(throwException)).Start();           
    }

    public static void throwException()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public static void UnhandledExHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs t) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is exception is unhandled.");            
    }
}

static class Program
{        
    static void Main()
    {            
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Form1.UnhandledExHandler);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that after executing `UnhandledExHandler`, `Forms1()` constructor does not return but keeps throwing Exception, I mean it keeps calling `throwException()` on a new thread. The end user experience popping of `MessageBox` continuously.  I know I must call `Application.Exit()` inside `UnhandledExHandler` to exit the app. But shouldnt this stop calling `UnhandledExHandler` after called once?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all of your projects are running in the same appdomain, this will work correctly. 
We have this exact code encapsulated in a common DLL that is shared among numerous applications.

An additional suggestion: if this is used in Windows Forms applications, you probably also want to add a handler for [System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx).

This serves as a backstop when, for example, someone forgets to add exception handling to a control event.

Comment: My question if u think above should show `MessageBox` once, why it keeps showing again and again? Build simple Win Forms app and check the behavior

Answer (score 1):

If you run your app without debugging you will get a message box and your app will be closed. You see many msg boxes because of the debugger work.

Your `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs.IsTerminating` is `true`, I guess you will not able to do anything with it in `CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` handler.

But you can handle it in `ThreadException` event handler.

Comment: Yes I checked the behavior out of VS, I run it by double clicking exe in `Debug` folder, so it showed a `MessageBox` then it displayed normal Program Stopped Working box and when I clicked Ok/Cancel the app was closed - is this desired or should it only return from `UnhandledExHandler`

Comment: In most cases your app will be unloaded (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.unhandledexceptioneventargs.isterminating(v=vs.110).aspx). You can try solution from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186854/how-to-prevent-an-exception-in-a-background-thread-from-terminating-an-applicati

Comment: I tested behavior after adding `Application.Exit()` and it still does not close silently after dismissal of `MessageBox` instead it shows Windows error message box saying `This app stopped working...`

Comment: This is working for me: `Application.Exit(new CancelEventArgs(false));`

Comment: I do also checked by adding `new CancelEventArgs(false)` to `Application.Exit()` after `MessageBox` it shows `App Stopped Working...Check online...Close app` Windows message.